# Can use DocuSign embedded signing with user's DocuSign account

Tags: docusignapi

We are planning to implement DocuSign embedded signing feature in our application. So, we crated a developer account with DocuSign.

**My Requirement:**

When user clicks request E-Signature option in the right click options of the document, DocuSign login screen should prompt and user should enter their own DocuSign username and password, not developer account username and password. In this case, our developer account will act as a middleware and communicate between the user account and DocuSign APIs. So, users who have paid account with DocuSign they can create Envelops using our App. So, we no need to pay for developer account.

Is this possible in DocuSign?

We tried this use case. But, DocuSign always requires developer account username and password to create Envelopes on behalf of the Sender.

Answer (score 0):

> In this case, our developer account will act as a middleware and
> communicate between the user account and DocuSign APIs

You cannot mix [developer account](https://developers.docusign.com/platform/account/) and production account in your app. Meaning, if you want your app to work with production accounts, it must use authentication token obtained from account.docusign.com not account-d.docusign.com

The right approach for your is to [go-live](https://developers.docusign.com/platform/go-live/) with your integration, so the IK is available in production and then configure your application to use production and not to use the developer account.